# Add to a table in the c# asp.net using the ASPNETDB.MDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

Is there a way to access a table that I have added to the default ASPNETDB.MDF database that is given to you when you create a new web page in asp.net 4.0. I have added a table called **BuilderTable** with 5 columns. Also I need it to increment ID on its own. I have set the is identity option to yes and the identity increment to 1 so how can I get it to work without sending it a value for the ID column in my code behind. Here is said code in c#:(I have it within a switch statement so dont mind the case 1)

```
     case "1":
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(usr.UserName, "Builder") == false)//if the user is not already in the builder role then add them
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(usr.UserName, "Builder");//here we add the user into the builder role

                string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection conn = null;
                conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    int nothing = 0;
                    string query = String.Format("INSERT INTO 'BuilderTable' VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}')", nothing, p.fName, p.lName, p.Address, usr.Email);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            break;
```

This code results in the error:

**Incorrect syntax near 'BuilderTable'**

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Thought I should clarify I have this declared elsewhere in the code

```
      string userName = Request.QueryString["user"];
    MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser(userName);
    ProfileCommon p = Profile.GetProfile(usr.UserName);
```

Comment: @valamas-AUS It solved one error but now it says **An explixit value for the identity column in table BuilderTable can only be specified when a column lis is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON** Any idea what that means?

Comment: @valamas-AUS Ahh yes this is the second question in my post. How can I insert without sending anything in to the ID field.

Comment: @valamas-AUS Ahh! I see I did not know you could do that. Ill try it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take away the single quotes from around the table name. I.e. 'BuilderTable'

*(You should be using parametrized queries. Look up "Sql Injection Attacks".)*

Your identity error is due to you trying to insert values into the identity field. You should insert values by specifying the fields.

```
 INSERT INTO BLAH (Fields,,,,) VALUES(Values,,,,,)
```